# UIView center, origin, and frame not making sense

Tags: ios, uiview

I have the following stats for a `UIView` in my app:

```
Frame: {{0, 111.0900252548883}, {374.99999999999994, 444.81994949022345}} 
AnchorPoint: {0.54933333333333334, 0.50329166666666669} 
Center: {193.18185551317976, 315.35327169496856}
```

The `UIView` has had a transform performed on it and while I know in the Apple docs it says the frame gets invalidated after a transform, the above numbers are still correct as I've verified them otherwise.

My question is, how do these numbers make sense? For instance, if the x origin of the frame starts at 0, and ends at 375, how is the x center 193.18185551317976 when the anchor point is 0.54933333333333334? Shouldn't the x center be 374.99999999999994 * 0.54933333333333334 = 205.99999999999997?

Comment: Anchor Point Explained
The anchorPoint defines where the node's texture is drawn relative to the node's position.
The anchorPoint has a value range of 0.0 to 1.0 (0% to 100%). If the anchorPoint is 0.5x0.5 (the default for nodes with textures) then the texture is centered on the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 0x0, then the texture's lower left corner aligns with the node's position. If the anchorPoint is 1x1 then the texture's upper right corner aligns with the node's position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor Point doesn't affect position at all. It only offsets the texture from the node's position. The problem with changing the anchorPoint is that it seemingly does affect position. The real problem usually comes later on, when you realise that changing the anchorPoint from its default also affects other node attributes. For example, rotation uses the anchorPoint as its center point. Scaling uses the anchorPoint as its centerPoint. Its a bit confusing. Try out [this](http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/How+The+Anchor+Point+Works+And+What+To+Use+It+For) wonderful article about anchorPoint. Helped me a lot to understand it clearly.

Comment: You can not use origin anymore after transformation. But for your own sake of using, you can calculate it by doing some math. Calculation will depend on the type of transformation you have done. For example, if it is rotation, then by using some trigonometry you can calculate the new origin.

Comment: Thanks. I deleted initial comment because wasn't sure if you were going to respond and was going to post it as another question. Thank you for your responses though.